# bootstrap tabs not working for history.back option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used the bootstrap tabs in my webpage

```
        <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs tab_new_vir" role="tablist">

    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" id="tab1-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab1-tab" aria-expanded="true" class="goto">Tab 1</a><span> | </span></li> 

    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" role="tab" id="tab2-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab2-tab" class="goto">Tab 2</a><span> | </span></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" role="tab" id="tab3-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab3" class="goto">Tab 3</a><span> | </span></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab4" role="tab" id="tab4-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab4" class="goto">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

By clicking the links the corresponding tabs opened.

By clicking the browser back button the corresponding tabs not opened.

For this I used the following code:

```
$('.goto').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        history.pushState( null, null, $(this).attr('href') );
    });
```

This is working.

By default, the tab1 is opened.Now I click tab2, and 3, and 4.

BY clicking the browser back button, it correspondingly opens the tab 3,2

But tab 1 is not opened. At that time the url is (http://url.com instead of http://url.com/#tab1)

How to fix this. Please help me

Comment: I think you cannot do anything with the browser actions and the page will not load when you press the back button

Answer (score 0):

remove class="active" and let him or her choose ^^ and normally it should work.

```
<li role="presentation">
    <a href="#tab1" id="tab1-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="tab1-tab" aria-expanded="true" class="goto">
        Tab 1
    </a>
    <span> | </span>
</li>
```